# V8 speed graphs

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, v8

Are there any graphs showing how V8 JavaScript Engine performance evolved over time?

Something like http://speed.pypy.org/

Comment: It's not completely up to date, but there is a graph in http://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html